# How to set a value in responseError so that the request can use it for every request in AngularJS interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I have a question on AngularJS interceptor.

I have 2 sets of users: legacy user and new user.
For every legacy user, to continue they have to reset their password first. That means they have to be authenticated first and this API sends a status code of 420 and then the user is redirected to Password reset page. And until the user resets his password, no other API calls are honored.

For this I'm using AngularJS interceptor.
In the `responseError` function I check if the status code I receive is 420. If it is, I set a variable in `$rootScope` so that all the subsequent requests can be suppressed based on this flag in the `request` function of the interceptor. But this value is always `undefined` after the redirect.

I also tried creating a new Service and injecting it in the interceptor and calling the service method to set a variable from `responseError`. Then, when I read the variable from `request` function it was always `undefined` after the redirect. So, no luck here either.

When the request method is executed the user would have been redirected to a new page. It shouldn't have reset the value in either `$rootScope` or in the `Service`, am I right?

What am I missing here? Can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('httpInterceptor', ["$window", "$q", "$rootScope", "$injector", function ($window, $q, $rootScope, $injector) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            // Read the value from the $rootScope. If it's true, cancel all the subsequent requests
            var redirected = $rootScope.app.redirected;

            console.log("request: redirected: " + redirected); // The value is always 'undefined' here

            var canceller = $q.defer();
            if (redirected) {
                // Canceling request
                canceller.resolve();
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            var statusCode = response.status;
            var newLocation = response.headers('location');
            if (statusCode === 420 && newLocation) { // Status code is 420. Redirect and set a flag in the $rootScope
                $rootScope.app.redirected = true;
                $window.location.href = newLocation;
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my efforts in solving this made me more knowledgeable today than I was yesterday. And, it feels so good to answer your own question :)

So, it looks like when used `$window.location.href`, it resets the $rootScope variable. As a fix, I replaced this line of code with `$location.path(newLocation)`

I switched back to using Service and I can see the value and it's not `undefined`